# PerformanceCounter extremely slow in connecting remote server

Tags: c#, performancecounter, remote-server

I try to use PerformanceCounter to monitor remote server information in a domain environment, like:

```
var counter = new PerformanceCounter("PhysicalDisk", "Disk Bytes/sec", "_Total", "REMOTE_SERVER");
```

there is only 1 line of code, running the above code will wait at least 50 seconds.

I tried to impersonate the admin etc, still same time.

I also tried with PowerShell get-counter, still more or less speed.

I tried with windows native Performance Monitoring Tool in computer management, connect to remote server, takes a few second only.

Any idea how to improve the connection speed?

Comment: Have you tried to do some profiling(network traffic sniffers, .net memory profilers)?

Comment: @aleksey.berezan sorry, no. I will.

Answer (score 0):

If you are monitoring your local computer, I've found if I try and monitor **localhost** I sometimes get 1 minute or greater waits when setting up my *PerformanceCounter* objects. If I instead use **127.0.0.1** it seems to help.

However, it still happens sometimes when monitoring remote machines. Will update if I find a solution, I believe there is an alternative library called PDH which I am about to look into.